# How to implement Binary Search Tree using an unsorted array with this specific formula?

Tags: java, arrays, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I need to use an array to implement a Binary Search tree with a specific formula: root is tree[0]. For any node at tree[n], the children of n (if any) will be found at tree[2n+1] (left branch) and tree[2n+2] (right branch). I am allowed to create a second array to store the BST. I am given a pseudo code:

```
for(i=1;i<;i++) {
   //Every iteration we start from the root node
     while (the cell is not empty){
       if(less than the element)
         go to 2i+1;
       else if (greater than the element)
         go to 2i+2;
```

So far this what I brainstormed:

```
public class BinarySearchTree {

    public void createBST(int[] array) {

        int[] tree = new int[array.length];

        int root = array[0];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] < root) {
                tree[(2*i)+1] = array[i];
            } else {
                array[(2 * i) + 2];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know where to go from here. I've been going at this for a while with no solution. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that pseudocode never creates a tree.

Any array values are only relevant for the comparison, the interesting information is the index. Also the "go to" modifies a position. That position needs to be stored somewhere (and starts from the root).

```
Integer[] tree = new Integer[array.length]
//the element to add is array[i]
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    //every iteration starts from the root node
    int pos = 0;
    //while the cell is not empty
    while (tree[pos] != null) {
        //if the cell is smaller than the element
        if (tree[pos] < array[i]) {
            //go to 2n+1
            pos = 2 * pos + 1;
        } else {
            //go to 2n+2
            pos = 2 * pos + 2;
        }
    }
    //add at the empty position.
    tree[pos] = array[i];
}
```

Note: I did not test this, it might throw a ArrayIndexOutBoundException a some point.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ran the code and there is an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException. I tried changing array.length and adding an extra if statement for when pos > array.length but no result. I think it might be the while loop statement. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: The underlying problem is, that by following your pseudocode adding the sequence `1;2;3;4` would be stored in the positions `0;2;6;14`, but the array would be only 4 long. The dumb solution would be to make the array just large enough. Other solutions: some kind of balancing, or _sorting_ `array` to become a binary search tree (not very efficient, but guaranteed to work).  Something I forgot to ask: is `array` sorted?

Comment: I just debugged my program and see what you're saying. No, array is not sorted. My professor stated that he does not want the array to be sorted. Sorry, I forgot to mention something: if the node has no left and/or right child, the corresponding position should be -1. Should I just make the array bigger since I need to do the former?

Comment: Of course creating a large array full of `-1` would solve the problem. But this would be inefficient as hell. An unsorted binary search tree is useless, so you have to sort it. And if you're creating an in this way sorted array, you can do it within the given one. (by ensuring `array[2* i + 1] < array[i] <= array[2 * 1 + 2` for every `0 <= i < array.length`)